# How to upsample numpy array with nearest neighbor without storing repeated values?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have an array 3x3 `a` and would like to upsample it to a 30x30 array `b` with nearest neighbor interpolation.

Is it possible to use a technique which does not actually store repeated values? Something similar on how `broadcasting` works in `numpy`.

e.g. I would like to have an object such that when I call `b[x, x]` with `0 < x < 10` I get `a[0, 0]`.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. What you can have is a (3,10,3,10) array which is constant along axes 1 and 3 and stores only 9 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is any way to do this using numpy. The way broadcasting works in numpy is that each axis has a "stride" parameter which controls how to calculate the next element along the axis. So for example:

```
In [1]: a = np.arange(10)

In [2]: a
Out[2]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [3]: b = a[::2]

In [4]: b
Out[4]: array([0, 2, 4, 6, 8])

In [5]: b.strides
Out[5]: (16,)

In [6]: a.strides
Out[6]: (8,)
```

In this case you can see that `b` is just a view of a obtained by doubling the stride along the first dimension. So when you access `b[1]`, the offset is calculated as `b.__array_interface__['data'][0] + b.strides[0]`.

In your case you essentially want a nonlinear stride, which isn't supported.

You could of course achieve this affect yourself by calculating the indexes yourself, i.e.:

```py
a[x//10,x//10]
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the `strides` representation.

Do you think that implementing a `C` routine to perform the division between the two arrays of different shape looping on every element and then calling `a[x//10, x//10]` could result in similar performance compared to a numpy division between two arrays of the same shape of the bigger one? e.g. would that save memory and upscaling time?

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve an object like the one you describe by creating a class that wraps a numpy array and implements a custom `__getitem__` method. That could look something like the below, where `factor` is the factor with which you want to upsample.

```py
class UpSampled:
    __slots__ = ('arr', 'factor')

    def __init__(self, arr, factor):
        self.arr = arr
        self.factor = factor

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.arr[key // self.factor]
```

You would then use it like below:

```py
o = UpSampled(np.array([
    UpSampled(np.array([0, 1, 2]), 10),
    UpSampled(np.array([3, 4, 5]), 10),
    UpSampled(np.array([6, 7, 8]), 10),
]), 10)

print(o[23][13])  # prints 7
```

If you need the object to be iterable you would then also implement `__next__` and `__iter__`:

```py
class UpSampled:
    __slots__ = ('arr', 'factor', '__index')

    def __init__(self, arr, factor):
        self.arr = arr
        self.factor = factor
        self.__index = 0

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.arr[key // self.factor]

    def __iter__(self):
        self.__index = 0
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        try:
            result = self[self.__index]
        except IndexError:
            raise StopIteration
        self.__index += 1
        return result
```

Though I'm not sure that would work well with libraries that specifically expect a numpy array.

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing this nice implementation. The issue is that in principle what I want to do is `b/a` where `a` shape is virtually upsampled on demand without storing and then using numpy vectorization for the mathematical operation. Something that will not work here. I will need to do such operation on 10k x 10k images, so upsampling and storing takes time and memory.